# What does "to stall around" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Please, tell me the meaning of "to stall around" in the sentences, for instance:

- I **stall around** outside the cafe.
- He **was stalling around** her house two days ago.
- She heard a click and the fighting **stalled around** her. (Marissa Meyer)

(added)

- [Two in the Saddle & Boone's Bounty by Vicki Lewis Thompson](https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=1426855915)
  Travis figured he'**d stall around** outside and ...
- [All at Sea: Twenty Years at the Helm of Tall Ships by Dominick Jones](https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=0786475803)
  Maybe we could ..., go straight out into the Channel, **stall around** outside for the tide to change...
- [Keeping You a Secret by Julie Anne Peters](https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=0316025755)
  And I **stall around** outside the restroom by the art studio so...

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried looking up the definitions of 'stall' and 'around'?

Comment: Yes, but I can't mix their meanings up to make sense for me. I guess, the meaning is likely near to "to walk around" but I'm not absolutly sure in it.

Comment: [around: 22. in the vicinity of](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/around)

Comment: I have never heard of this usage. Where did you hear it?

Comment: @Gandalf In the novels.

Comment: @Gandalf,

* Two in the Saddle & Boone's Bounty by Vicki Lewis Thompson  

https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=1426855915  

Travis figured he'**d stall around** outside and ...
* All at Sea: Twenty Years at the Helm of Tall Ships by Dominick Jones  
https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=0786475803  
Maybe we could ..., go straight out into the Channel, **stall around** outside for the tide to change...
* Keeping You a Secret by Julie Anne Peters<br/>
https://books.google.ru/books?isbn=0316025755<br/>
And I **stall around** outside the restroom by the art studio so...

Comment: I've never heard [***stall around***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+stalled+around%22). It sounds to me like a "copying error" based on mis-hearing [***stalk around.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+stalked+around%22)

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first usage is not a common usage.
The second two use the word "stall" to denote a lack of activity. Often wrestlers or boxers get penalized for 'stalling.' The word "around" is added as a preposition.
The best usage is "He is stalling," not "He is stalling around."

Answer (score 2):

In the first two sentences, **stall around** is a [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) roughly equivalent to **hang around**, or **loiter in the vicinity of**.

In the third sentence, it is not a phrasal verb. It means that fighting stalled, specifically the fighting that was happening around her.

Comment: We all know what a phrasal verb is. Could you please provide a link proving that this particular phrasal verb actually exists?

Comment: I'm not sure everyone knows what a phrasal verb is @Gandalf. I think it's a helpful element of this answer.

Comment: Whether or not it's *called* a phrasal verb doesn't explain anything, unless the phrase actually exists.  You can find examples of the two words adjacent to each other on Google where "stall" is a noun, not a verb, but that is irrelevant for making sense of the OP's examples.

Comment: @Gandalf you know English, right? Look at the OP's question for two examples. You read them and you know what they mean. See [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for three more examples.

Comment: @alephzero *CLYDE: I thought maybe he and Connie ran off. (Smells coffee, musing) Is it Kona?... Is it the Hawaiian?... LUCY: You're supposed to taste it, and say what it is. Not stall around. CLYDE: My nose has lost its edge.* (American Theatre 24(6) p. 53)

Comment: A verb + proposition does not constitute a phrasal verb. Sometimes it is just a verb + preposition. From your link: _"This semantic unit cannot be understood based upon the meanings of the individual parts in isolation, but rather it can be taken as a whole. In other words, the meaning is non-compositional and thus unpredictable."_

Comment: @Gandalf and...? Did you want some kind of proof? You'll see my earlier comment showing an example of *stall around* at the end of a sentence. In that case the preposition governs no object (it's not pre-posed), because it's not a preposition, it's lexically bound to the verb.